# what does "can not write log (is /dev/pts mounted") mean in apt-get in Ubuntu-on-Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

What exactly does the error message beginning with E: mean? I assume it has to do with the file structure on Ubuntu-on-Windows, but what exactly?

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
      os-prober
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      libxslt1.1
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libxslt1.1 xmlstarlet
    0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 435 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 1023 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libxslt1.1 amd64 1.1.28-2build1 [145 kB]
    Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe xmlstarlet amd64 1.5.0-1 [290 kB]
    Fetched 435 kB in 3s (134 kB/s)
    **E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - openpty (2: No such file or directory)**
    Selecting previously unselected package libxslt1.1:amd64.
    (Reading database ... 28723 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../libxslt1.1_1.1.28-2build1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.28-2build1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package xmlstarlet.
    Preparing to unpack .../xmlstarlet_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb .
```

Comment: It means that something is broken, because *nix (including Ubuntu) do not have drive letters, and `E:` would clearly be a Windows drive letter. With that being said, this isn't a programming question and therefore it is off-topic here. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. If you need more info, the guidelines for this site can be found in the [help].

Comment: some MS folks have answered a similar question here [https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/80](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/80)

Comment: `E:` just means "Error", nothing to do with drive letters...